# Send the dropdown value for each row form

Tags: javascript, php, select, input

I have a dropdown value out of forms and a table wih many rows to submit data.
What I'd like to do is during submit of each row submit also the getting value from the drop down list.
My table it's look like [image: this] My code for dropdrown list is

```
<div class="panel-heading">
   <label for="cat">Select a Category</label>
      <select class="form-control" id='category' name="category" data-live-search="true" style="max-width:40%;" >
         <?=$html?>
      </select>
  </div>
```

And the part for table rows is

```
<form id="sync-cat" action="controllers/product-add.php" target="_blank">
     <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?=$product['id']?>">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Sync Products</button>
</form>
```

I've tried with javascript copying selected value in hidden input but that run only for the first row. Also I've tried a hidden input above the dropdown list copying the select option but I didn't find a way to get value when I use submit button "Sync Products"

Answer (score 1):

They should share the same form in HTML so that when the form is posted all available information is present in the form. Regardless your dropdown should also be in it's own form (if you don't put them in the same form) to be valid.

If you wanted to continue as is ignoring the proper things to consider above you could do it with something like this. This solution will make things a bit more complicated. I would recommend taking the above advice.

```
var form = document.getElementById('sync-cat')

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var valueFromDropDown = document.getElementById('category').value;

  // Post the rest of the form
});
```

Follow the rest of this [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript) to complete the JavaScript post